# Combining Python f-string and r-string not behaving as expected

Tags: python, string, text, nlp, f-string

I have a variable that contains a string, that I'd like to print literally, so the newline is escaped.  Printing the variable does not escape the newline:

```
bad_string = 'http://twitter.com/blo\r\n+omberg'
print(bad_string)
>>> http://twitter.com/blo
+omberg
```

Printing the value using an r-string results in what I'd want:

```
print(r'http://twitter.com/blo\r\n+omberg')
>>> http://twitter.com/blo\r\n+omberg
```

However, using an f-string with the variable, and combining it with an r-string, does not:

```
print(rf'{bad_string}')
>>> http://twitter.com/blo
+omberg
```

I'm confused why this happens.  I'd expect the combination of r and f string to print it literally.  How can I print the literal value of a string variable with an f-string?

I'm using Python 3.6.13

Comment: try something like this: ```bad_string = r'http://twitter.com/blo\r\n+omberg' ; print(f"{bad_string}")```

Comment: you can try `print(f'{bad_string.encode()}')`

Comment: thanks @tgpz, that works.  However I'm loading pre-defined string variables - is there an easy way to convert the string variable to a raw string variable?

Comment: thanks @Abhishek, that seems to output a b-string though - I'd still need to convert it to a plain string?

Comment: yeah using `decode()`

Comment: Interestingly `print(f'{bad_string.encode().decode()}')` doesn't work, but `print(f'{bad_string.encode("unicode_escape").decode()}')` seems to

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Raw strings only concern themselves with the static literal part, so your `rf'{bad_string}'` is the same as `bad_string`.

Depending on what this is for, the `repr` builtin may be what you need

```py
In [71]: print(repr("string\nwith\nnewline"))
'string\nwith\nnewline'
```

Or you can simply replace the newlines using the replace method.

There's also the `unicode_escape` "encoding", but this'll also replace any non ascii value:

```py
In [77]: "\n".encode("unicode_escape").decode()
Out[77]: '\\n'

In [78]: "仮".encode("unicode_escape").decode()
Out[78]: '\\u4eee'
```